# failed to resolve RegisterPlugin libdiff_drive_controller.so:undefined symbol

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all:
I am a beginner to ros, and I met a problem when I am learning gazebo which is as followed:

```
Error [Plugin.hh:147] Failed to resolve RegisterPlugin: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libdiff_drive_controller.so: undefined symbol: RegisterPlugin[ INFO] [1438586829.560869251, 0.021000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
```

I do not know how to solve this problem. Can anyone help me? Thanks very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215125/failed-to-resolve-registerplugin-libdiff_drive_controller.so:undefined-symbol/) by [zxawangxiaomu](https://answers.ros.org/users/23437/zxawangxiaomu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure to

```
 #include <gazebo/common/Plugin.hh>
```

at the beginning of the plugin source, and register the plugin with Gazebo with

```
GZ_REGISTER_WORLD_PLUGIN( YourWorldPluginClass ) //Different function for each type of Gazebo plugin
```

These solved the issue for a plugin I was writing.

I realize this is an old question, but this was the first search hit I got when trying to solve a similar problem.

---

Originally posted by [jwatson_utah_edu](https://answers.ros.org/users/27605/jwatson_utah_edu/) with karma: 56 on 2016-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hillripper21](https://answers.ros.org/users/36849/hillripper21/) on 2020-06-02**:
Top include fixed my issue even now Ubuntu 20.04, Gazebo 11. Note the tutorial for the plugins does not mention this...

**Comment by [kodplayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/53791/kodplayer/) on 2021-02-08**:
Works even for Gazebo 9